# How to open default wp image editor screen dynamically?

Tags: images, media, media-library, media-modal

I'm displaying gallery images of the logged-in users on the frontend with the edit button. Now I want to link that edit button with the default WP Image Editor screen that includes tools like crop, flip, etc.

Is there any way to open that screen providing the image ID?

[image]

Thanks